# How to create UWP Blank app in c using Visual studio 2017?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Our requirement is to create UWP app In visual studio 2017 using c,In visual studio 2017 options are their only for c#,c++ and js.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot build pure C UWP apps. Windows Runtime is compatible with C#, C++ and JavaScript only.

The best bet would be to port the code to C++.

Comment: Our project backed is already developed in C.Is it any option is their to use that code to run in c++ UWP.

Comment: Our project backend is already developed in c,Is it any way to use that code in UWP.

Comment: Alternatively you could build a desktop app and then package it as UWP using Windows Desktop Bridge

Comment: Otherwise someone with C++ knowledge may be able to help, I am more of a C# guy :-D

Comment: In Visual studio 17 option is only their to create desktop app in c++,How to do the same in c.